# How do I make two circular borders?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a site and almost the only thing that's left is a slide number indicator. The problem can be viewed in this link:

URL:
http://parimpex.sem.lv/logistics-insurance/

VirusTotal:
https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/f270075d5d8e26607cd6f06b49459e0c99a6a6c09369ffa2f77d8e23ee5d178f/detection

The current slide indicator looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3dDk.png

The end result is supposed to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u26o.png

I have tried using multiple circular box-borders, but that didn't do it.

The white part of the indicator is done, but there has to be a transparent space, and then an orange border.

Please guide!

Comment: Include some code, referencing to external links is not sufficient

Comment: @JessedeBruijne The content is generated by a plugin, copying the HTML doesn't work.

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).  If all you are after is an element with 2 circular borders, then all you need to do is create an [MCVE] with that part of your html and css in.  If the content is generated by a plugin, it still leaves you with some html so you can always inspect the element and copy the rendered html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.global_slider .flickity-page-dots .dot {
    position: relative;
}

.global_slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected:before {
    content: '';
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you very much! It tells me to wait 7 minutes until I can accept an answer.

Comment: why do you need `position: absolute` ?

Comment: this is not proper approach

Comment: @Andy I'm curious, this worked for me, but since you say this is not the proper approach, can you show me any other? Thanks!

Comment: you can check it a bit above

Comment: @Andy Didn't see your answer, going to check it!

Comment: I added jsfiddle link as well

Comment: @Andy Ah, your solution would be perfect, but I need the black bit to be transparent. His answer does that.

Comment: Why its not a prpoer method? Psedo-elements are ther to be used.Instead of creating an extra div , we acn apply psedo-elements

Comment: @Anuresh using position `absolute` may break piece of layout unless you know how it behaves and so on. Moreover pseudo selectors do not work in older browsers

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions is here:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #000; 
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 2px #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dbza1px/1/